# Copying a row, inserting multiple new rows with the pasted info on multiple sheets Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG2mc.png) This is where all the items are with each region code

I have a "New Item" worksheet, a "Data" worksheet, and a "View" worksheet in the same workbook.
In my "New Item" worksheet, I have a section B2:H2 for inputing new items and click a button to run the macro.  I need help fixing the error.  It runs but adds a "true" to each point instead of the copied section.

I need the macro to add a line, copy the region code (in column A; there are over 30 regions but every item is added to a region by default), insert the B2:H2 in the B:H columns of the new line on the "Data" Sheet and also just add it to the end of the "View" sheet.
It keeps inputting true now.  Why does it do this? Also, why does the code not copy the B2:H2?  I am fairly new to VBA.

*Also if possible, if there was a way to adjust the chart's Selected Data  on the View sheet to add a line to the viewed data, that would be great.  Ex: the chart shows 50 lines, and it adds another line to the selected data through the macro.*

Thank you in advance for all suggestions.  I can clarify anything or upload the excel if needed.
Here is the code so far:

```
Sub AddItem()
   Sheets("Data").Select
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim rowPtr As Long
        lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For rowPtr = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & rowPtr)) Then
          If Range("A" & rowPtr) <> Range("A" & rowPtr - 1) Then
            Range("A" & rowPtr).EntireRow.Insert
          End If
        End If
  Next
   Sheets("New Item").Select
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim copySheet As Worksheet
   Dim pasteSheet1 As Worksheet

   Set copySheet = Worksheets("New Item")
   Set pasteSheet1 = Worksheets("Data")

   copySheet.Range("B2:H2").Copy
   pasteSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you can start by fixing your variable in this line you only have pasteSheet, but you declared it as pasteSheet1.  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: My apologies, I have edited this code to not have the actual names of the variables, sheets and such.   This was not the problem, but I appreciate a vigilant eye.

Answer (score 0):

So im not sure if this is what you want.

```
Sub Add()
Dim Data As Worksheet, NItem As Worksheet, View As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set NItem = Worksheets("New Item")
Set Data = Worksheets("Data")
Set View = Worksheets("View")

lRow = View.Cells(View.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Data.Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
NItem.Range("B2:H2").Copy
Data.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
View.Cells(lRow + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But this will add a line in Row 2 in the Datasheet, paste in the values. (Your `For` Loop inserts a new line after every entry, why?). It also pastes it in the viewsheet. Other than that please avoid using `.Select` and objectify `.Range, .Cells etc.` like you've done in the second part of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The reason for the for loop inserting a new line after each entry:  every region automatically adds the "item."  There are 30+ regions that each get the new item by default when we add a new item.  So I need to paste the item, then copy the region code in the A column

Comment: But that would mean the data is duplicated 30 times, why then the regions?  And in which sheet is the region code? you didnt mention it in your question. It may help if you add a screenshot to your question with the different sheets.

Comment: The "View" sheet is a global summary essentially for the items while the "Data" sheet provides the individual region data.   I have created an example screenshot so that the question may be easier to understand.  Ideally, the macro runs so that with each new item inserted, the item is copied to each region in the "Data" tab and also one copy is made in the "View" tab.

Comment: So in that ss, some data is not there for all regions, how can that happen, i mean you said it will be inserted mutiple times and then how can the data for one region be different then? Also wouldnt it make more sense if you put  in mutiple regions in col A instead of mutiple duplicated entrys? and you just could paste it in the end and apply an autofilter for regions so you dont worry about shifting or what ever. And with your old loop it would create exponentionally more entrys after each run not 30 every time.

Comment: Also how do the regions are selected? you only copy from B:H.

Comment: The idea is that you add the item to every region, then delete the ones not being sold in the region.   In reality, there are 30+ regions and usually only 1 is excluded from getting the product.   Thus, the idea is that a new line is inserted between each region, the region ID is copied to the blank line in column A, then the rest of the information for the item is copied into B:H.

Comment: Im just questioning the way you present the data. So first of all you would not insert the data between rows. Instead you would add them to the bottom of the table and then you can use an `AutoFilter` to sort after the regions. Other than that i feel like it would make more sense to have a column for each region rather then inserting them in column a and so duplicating the data 30 times with the only difference being the region, this would make the list very long if you have more than couple items. If you want the item 30 times then you should also look into using `Autofilter`